# Переход по ссылке только после второго клика?

Tags: jquery

Нужно запретить переход по ссылке классу .left-bottom-header__form при первом клике и разрешить только после второго. Не могу понять как это сделать

```js
$(".left-bottom-header__form").on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".bottom-header__logo").addClass("_hidden");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".left-bottom-header__form").addClass("_active");
        }, 50);
        $(".left-bottom-header__form").addClass("_active");
        $(".bottom-header__left").addClass("_active");
        $(".left-bottom-header__input").addClass("_active");
    })
    $('body').on('click', function () {
        $(".bottom-header__logo").removeClass("_hidden");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".left-bottom-header__form").removeClass("_active");
        }, 50);
        $(".bottom-header__left").removeClass("_active");
        $(".left-bottom-header__input").removeClass("_active");
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".left-bottom-header__form").on('click', function (e) {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('already-clicked')) {
    $(this).addClass('already-clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  ...
});
```